# Не сохраняется фото в фотогалерею на iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, swift

Сохраняю фото в фото галерею на iPhone/iPad, поэтому вызываю метод `WriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

Появляется сообщение "**Saved!**". Фото на устройстве не появляется

```
 @IBAction func buttonSavePressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageViewFinal.image!, self,


#selector(SaveAfterFilterScreen.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil) }

    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error:
NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafePointer<Void>) {
            if error == nil {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Фото
сохранилось", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default,
handler: nil))
                presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "**Save error**", message:
error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default,
handler: nil))
                presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Comment: какой номер ошибки и какой description?

Comment: код сохранения работает, error = nil, а фото в коллекции не появляется.                                                                                                  Update:  поправил код, были местами перепутаны ошибка и нормальная работа.

Comment: что у вас в error.localizedDescription?

Comment: error.localizedDescription не появляется,  error = nil.

Comment: что то я запутался. save error есть, f localizedDescription нет? или уже и save error пропал?

Comment: я написал выше, у меня в коде было перепутано местами: в случае сохранения я писал "Save error". А программа все-равно шла по ветке сохранения.

Comment: то есть ошибки нет, но и фото не появляется?

Comment: да, именно так, фото не появляется. Раньше я получал сообщение "Программа <моя> запрашивает разрешение на доступ к фото, разрешить?"   а теперь и такого нет.

Comment: в настройках у приложения доступ к фото уже стоит

Comment: чисто для моего спокойствия: метод `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:` вызывает система или вы сами?

Comment: этот метод я вызываю.  вот, он указан у меня в селекторе UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageViewFinal.image!, self,
#selector(SaveAfterFilterScreen.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

Comment: а не, перепутал, подумал, что это метод делегата. Тогда проверйте если ли на устройстве место, и посмотрите во всех фотоальбомах, может оно просто не там, где вы его ожидаете

Comment: Проверил, руками фото легко делается и сохраняется на айпаде, потом его видно в приложении "Фото". А вот через программно не могу сохранить.

Comment: попробуйте сохранить без обработки `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageViewFinal.image!,nil,nil,nil)`

Comment: А вот так вот фотографии появились!

Comment: значит селектор поломанный :)

Comment: я брал код из руководства отсюда   https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/13/5/saving-to-the-ios-photo-library

Comment: у вас селектор не так же объявлен, как в примере. у них там `#selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:))`

Comment: это же записи равнозначные в контексте класса?  SaveAfterFilterScreen.image =  image.   Селектор вызывался, отрабатывал.

Comment: единственное отличие которое я пока вижу